# How to create a factory for post where it also enters data in meta table for that post in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, factory, record, faker

using factory is a cleaner way to create seed data.
I can generate the result from another method of foreach or for loop. but how to do it with the factory ?

below is the post factory page

```php
<?php

/** @var \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factory $factory */

use App\Post;
use App\MetaData;
use Faker\Factory;

$factory->define(Post::class, function () {
    $faker = Faker\Factory::create('en_IN');
    $w = $faker->unique()->sentence.' '.mt_rand(0,1000);
    $r = [
        'title' => $w,
        'slug' => strtolower(str_replace(' ', '-', $w)),
        'banner' => 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/600x600',
        'content' => $faker->text,
        'views' => mt_rand(0,1000),
        'status' => rand(0,1),
        'creator_id' => mt_rand(0,100),
        'moderator_id' => mt_rand(0,100),
    ];

    $factory->define(MetaData::class, function () {
        return [
            'for' => 'article',
            'record_id' => $r->id,
            'title' => $w,
            'slug' => strtolower(str_replace(' ', '-', $w)),
            'description' => $faker->sentences,
            'banner' => 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/600x600',
            'keywords' => $faker->words,
            'status' => 1,
            'creator_id' => mt_rand(0,100),
            'moderator_id' => mt_rand(0,100),
        ];
    });
    return $r;
});
```

I want to do something like this, but end up with an error like below:

```php
   ErrorException  : Undefined variable: factory

  at /Users/dragonar/Dev/pdp/database/factories/PostFactory.php:23
    19|         'creator_id' => mt_rand(0,100),
    20|         'moderator_id' => mt_rand(0,100),
    21|     ];
    22| 
  > 23|     $factory->define(MetaData::class, function () {
    24|         return [
    25|             'for' => 'article',
    26|             'record_id' => $r->id,
    27|             'title' => $w,

  Exception trace:

  1   Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions::handleError("Undefined variable: factory", "/Users/dragonar/Dev/pdp/database/factories/PostFactory.php", [Object(Faker\Generator), "Aut voluptatum sed aut beatae. 380"])
      /Users/dragonar/Dev/pdp/database/factories/PostFactory.php:23

  2   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factory::{closure}(Object(Faker\Generator), [])
      /Users/dragonar/Dev/pdp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/FactoryBuilder.php:273

  Please use the argument -v to see more details.
```

if this solves, I also want to add categories and tags to the same post.

Answer (score 1):

please try this

```
$factory->define('App\MetaData', function($faker) use ($factory) {
    // Your stuff here
});
```

Comment: I upvoted it, due to it being a more obvious solution to the problem, than the answer I provided.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are trying to define the child inside the factory of the parent.

You are getting an `ErrorException  : Undefined variable: factory` error, that tells you that `$factory` is not defined. This is because you are doing it in the closure for the post factory.

One way you can get around this, is to reference the post when creating the meta data, so you do not create them both at the same time.

```
<?php

/** @var \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factory $factory */

use App\Post;
use App\MetaData;
use Faker\Factory;

$factory->define(Post::class, function () {
    $faker = Faker\Factory::create('en_IN');
    $w = $faker->unique()->sentence.' '.mt_rand(0,1000);
    return [
        'title' => $w,
        'slug' => strtolower(str_replace(' ', '-', $w)),
        'banner' => 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/600x600',
        'content' => $faker->text,
        'views' => mt_rand(0,1000),
        'status' => rand(0,1),
        'creator_id' => mt_rand(0,100),
        'moderator_id' => mt_rand(0,100),
    ];
});

$factory->define(MetaData::class, function () {
    return [
        'for' => 'article',
        'record_id' => factory(Post::class)->id,
        'title' => $w,
        'slug' => strtolower(str_replace(' ', '-', $w)),
        'description' => $faker->sentences,
        'banner' => 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/600x600',
        'keywords' => $faker->words,
        'status' => 1,
        'creator_id' => mt_rand(0,100),
        'moderator_id' => mt_rand(0,100),
    ];
});
```

When doing it like this, you first create the post, then you create the metadata and reference the post when creating it. However, I am not sure that helps you with your issue. So what you could do is create a helper class, where you can pass in some overrides for both classes, in case you want to control what data goes into each model.

Can be done like so:

```
<?php

use App\Post;
use App\MetaData;

class FactoryHelper {
  public static function createPostWithMetaData(array $postAttributes = [], array $metaDataAttributes = [])
  {
      $post = factory(Post::class)->create(postAttributes);
      $metaData = factory(MetaData::class)->create(array_merge([
          'record_id' => $post->id
      ], $metaDataAttributes));

      return $post;
  }
}
```